# Change android emulator sdcard permission

Tags: android, permissions, android-emulator, android-sdcard

I want to change my android emulator sdcard read only permission, for that I typed

```
mount -o remount,rw /mnt/sdcard
```

in adb shell. But it shows

```
Usage: mount [-r] [-w] [-o options] [-t type] device directory
```

Whats the problem in the command I have written in the adb shell.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must write something like this:

mount -o remount rw /sdcard

Comment: Did you mount sdcard ?

Comment: Yes it mounted properly.